# Problemas al instalar bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Recientemente estoy trabajando en un proyecto web el cual actualmente utiliza bootstrap 3, sin embargo cuando quiero actualizar de la versión 3 a la 4, presento inconvenientes al instalar los plugins, con bootstrap 3 yo descargaba los archivos (boostrap.min.css, jquery, bootstrap.min.js) y los llamaba en el HTML, pero con Bootstrap 4 estoy tratando de hacer lo mismo, pero cuando trato de hacerlo con los archivos descargados en mi computadora (localmente) no me funciona, la página se desordena y quedan los botones entre otras cosa hacia la izquierda. Alguien podría decirme, por qué sucede esto?

Es importante que la instalación se realice con los archivos descargados y no usando el cdn que te otorga bootstrap.

Comment: Por favor, has el [tour], lee [¿Como elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concretamente, debes sustituir las class que interfieren en el diseño respibsive por clases de flexbox que es lo que viene implementado en boostrap 4. Puedes ver la sencilla documentacion de flexbox en la web de w3school.